# ORA-00904: "hours": недопустимый идентификатор

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
  "group",
  (ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE("date_reg", 'yyyy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS'))*24)) AS "hours"
FROM
  "base"."table"
where
  "hours" < 3;
```

Не пойму, что не так =(

Comment: date_reg = '2015.07.30 04:19:20'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать так:

```
SELECT "group", (ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE("date_reg", 'yyyy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS'))*24)) AS "hours" 
FROM "base"."table" 
where (ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE("date_reg", 'yyyy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS'))*24)) < 3
```

Или так:

```
select "group", "hours"
from
(
  SELECT "group", (ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE("date_reg", 'yyyy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS'))*24)) AS "hours" 
  FROM "base"."table" 
)
where "hours" < 3;
```

Comment: Хороший ответ не только (и не столько) должен делать работу за спрашивающего, а объяснять в чем было и учить.

Comment: @KromStern Я с Вами полностью согласен. Но, перед отправкой ответа я увидел, что объяснение по этому поводу Вы уже дали. А ответ я все таки написал для того, чтобы показать несколько возможных вариантов решения проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя в `WHERE` обращаться к названиям полей из `SELECT` заданных через `AS`

Один из вариантов решения - обернуть запрос в селект и фильтровать его:

```
select 
    t.* 
from 
    (SELECT
      "group",
      (ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE("date_reg", 'yyyy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS'))*24)) AS "hours"
    FROM
      "base"."table"
    ) t
where
  t.hours < 3
```

Comment: а как решить подобный вопрос?

Comment: @VladimirLenkov Дополнил ответ